# Reuse WebGLRenderTarget

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two scenes: the main one, which renders a textured plane, and the second one, which should be rendered to a texture. This texture should be used as a map for the plane from the main scene.

All `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` examples for some reason redraw both scenes every frame, but I want my second scene to be rendered to a texture only once. Than the result of rendering should be stored as any other texture.

A simplified fiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bktdyg79/1/). In `animate()` function you can remove `if(i === 0)` so that the second scene will be rendered every frame.

Comment: Can you think of a better title for your post -- one that is more descriptive of the issue?

Comment: @WestLangley Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not really. Oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture loading is asynchronous. You need to ensure the texture is loaded before you use it.

One solution is to call `animate()` in the loader callback.

```
beginTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "https://i.imgur.com/eoQwyRb.png", animate );
```

Another solution would be to use a loading manager.

three.js r.102